# Finding out if two linked lists intersect

Tags: linked-list

The question is:
Given two linked lists. Find out if they intersect.

There are many complex solutions given to this question. What is wrong with finding the last node and checking if they are the same for the two lists?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *intersect*? That they contain the same nodes or the same data?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the discussion around this question I have seen is more interested in finding out the exact node where the two lists intersect. If you just want to know if they intersect, comparing the last node would be sufficient.